# backbone collection contains no models even though the models were already created

Tags: backbone.js

I'm really confused about something regarding collections and models in backbone. Since I'm learning backbone, I haven't been able to fully understand it. I'm working on a backbone project that displays the question with branching logic; the next question that appears is based on the answer to the current question. I created a collection and model that stores (if this is the proper terminology) the response which is then retrieved in a separate view (an email form view) where these responses are added to the message box. Here's my collection to the response.

```
App.Collections.ResponseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.ResponseModel
});
```

and this is the model:

```
App.Models.ResponseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",

    defaults: {
        response: '',
        answer: ''
    }
});
```

which is created like this:

```
saveResponse: function (qModel, option) {
    var qid = qModel.get('question_id');


        var mod = this.response.find(function (model1) {
            return model1.get('_id') == qModel.get('question_id');
        });

        if (typeof (mod) == "undefined") {

            var responseModel = new App.Models.ResponseModel({
                _id: qModel.get('question_id'),
                response: qModel.get('question'),
                answer: option
            });

            this.response.add(responseModel);
        }
        else {
            mod.set('answer', option);
        }

},
```

In the view which displays the questions, I instantiated the model and added the response to it which is then added to the collection. This works fine - the responses are added to the model and also it is added to the collection. Now, I want to retrieve this collection and fetch the response from each model so that it's added in the textarea. So, this is what I did in the email view..

```
var options = new App.Collections.ResponseCollection();
```

But when I print the collection in console, this is what I see - there's no model in the collection

```
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

These data are not saved and retrieved from the database. These responses are added to the model only to retrieve it later to be added to the email form.

I'm confused why it doesn't show me any models in the collection

Comment: You need to pass the same instance of `App.Collections.ResponseCollection` from one view to the other the other view. At the moment, it sounds like you are creating two different instances of that collection.

Comment: @fbynite That's exactly what it was. Thanks for your help.